# Display Vimeo in WebView iFrame on Android

Tags: android, iframe, webview, vimeo

I am trying to create an app that displays a WebView with an embedded iframe that will show a Vimeo video.  When I load the WebView the iframe is just a black box that will not show the video or do anything when I click on it.

```
mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String data = new String("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:fb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'><head>" +
"<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />" +
"<title>Northern African and Middle Eastern Peoples </title>" +
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='./style.css' type='text/css' media='screen' /></head><body>" +
"<div id='content'><div class='post'>" + 

"<iframe style='margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;' src=http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + mRssVideoItem.getVimeoId() + "?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0' width='880' height='497' frameborder='0'>" +
"</iframe><h1>" + mRssVideoItem.getTitle() + "</h1><div class='timestamp'>" + formattedDate + "</div>" + mRssVideoItem.getDescription() + "</div></div></body></html>"); 

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
});
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/.", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I have searched for several days and can not find anything that helps.

**Update:**  I am still struggling with this.  I have a couple of different things going on that I don't quite understand.  First I thought I had the Vimeo Videos working using the suggestion below.  However, I came back to the project today and am just seeing a black box.  Another problem is the "scaling" of the view.  Sometimes when I load the video, the entire view appears in the screen.  Other times it is like the image is zoomed it and the words are much larger than I thought.  It also seems to change when I alter rotation of the device.  Below is the HTML I am using with loadDataWithBaseURL.

http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:fb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'>Northern African and Middle Eastern Peoples

## No One But God

May 14, 2013A young Syrian father shares the story of his family's escape from the Syrian civil war and their struggles finding a new life in Jordan.

---

The suggestion above seems to work as long as I don't change the WebSettings LayoutAlgorithm to NARROW_COLUMNS.  Does anyone know why this would not allow the video to show up? A second question is sometimes when the "page" loads everything looks great and other times the content  is really big and the image goes off the side of the screen.  It seems it may have something to do with rotation and scaling or initialization since if I rotate to landscape and back to portrait, the image seems to correct itself.  See images below.

[image: Good Image]

[image: Bad Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to play a vimeo's video inside a webview while looking around a few days ago. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/bilthon/VimeoTest). It makes use of the HTML5WebView from [this](https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/) other project.

But the HTML5WebView is just a wrapper around a regular WebView specially tuned play the video. Specifically you need to:

1- Turn on the Javascript
2- Implement a class that extends WebChromeClient and implement the onShowCustomView and onHideCustomView methods.

My problem now has to do with grabbing those controls you see when the video is fullscreen. If somehow you or someone else manages to do that any help will be appreciated.

Nelson

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I could not seem to get the code you referenced to work either.  It would display the initial page but then it would not play the video.

Comment: I got it to work but had to use an Activity (like in the sample) instead of a Fragment.  Has anyone used this or something similar with a Fragment?

Comment: @James : i am trying to show the vimeo video in a fragment.. Do you have the code? i am using webview(when using html5webview it shows error), sometimes the video works... some times not..